# Question about sanskrit song

Tags: sanskrit, bhakti

I'd like to have the proper lyrics of the following song Om Namo Bhagavate Vasudevaya by Deepak Ram & Tara Devi, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PjvB-7AoTO8

The lyrics shown in that video are wrong in several places.
I have tried to search those lyrics in the internet, but I haven't found them. I have tried to write them down, but I'm unable to get them by hear and be sure they are correct.
Could anyone help me this? From providing a link of the lyrics, writing them down, or by handling me a resource where most of the visnu names are listed (and conjugated).

Also, if possible, could anyone let me know whether this is a traditional composition or whether the song is a modern arrange? Is the pronunciation of the singer mostly correct?